# Dotnet Nlog Mail Target Bold Body Html Text

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

The mail target is below is what i have currently. I would like to bold the text "Date" and "Calling Class" in the email body. What is the best approach for this? Thanks.

```
    <target name="gmail" type="Mail"
    smtpServer="smtp.gmail.com"
    smtpPort="587"
    smtpAuthentication="Basic"
    smtpUsername="xxxxxx"
    smtpPassword="xxxxxx"
    from="xxxxxx"
    to="xxxxxx"
    enableSsl="true"
    html ="true"
    replaceNewlineWithBrTagInHtml ="true"
    subject="Example - ERROR - ${exception:format=Message}"
    body="Date:${longdate}${newline}Calling Class: ${callsite}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
body="Date:<strong>${longdate}</strong>${newline}
      Calling Class: <strong>${callsite}</strong>"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using NLog version: 4.5.11 with NLog.MailKit version 3.0.0.

This worked for me:

```
body="Date:&lt;strong&gt;${longdate}&lt;/strong&gt;${newline}
      Calling Class: &lt;strong&gt;${callsite}&lt;/strong&gt;"
```

Note that I escaped the less than and greater than characters.

Comment: This worked but pretty ugly.  Have you found any good sample body layouts for nlog for email?